# Creating a Dictionary of Metrics

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, max, mean, median

I have to create a function with the following instructions; Write a function that calculates the mean, median, variance, standard deviation, minimum and maximum of of list of items. You can assume the given list is contains only numerical entries, and you may use numpy functions to do this.

Function Specifications:

Function should allow a list as input. It should return a dict with keys 'mean', 'median', 'std', 'var', 'min', and 'max', corresponding to the mean, median, standard deviation, variance, minimum and maximum of the input list, respectively. The standard deviation and variance values must be unbiased. Hint: use the ddof parameter in the corresponding numpy functions! All values in the returned dict should be rounded to 2 decimal places.

I was experimenting but came across an error. Would anyone be able to tell me what I have done wrong?

```
### START FUNCTION
def dictionary_of_metrics(items):
    my_list = np.mean(ebp_df.head()), np.median(ebp_df.head()), np.std(ebp_df.head()), 
    np.var(ebp_df.head()), np.min(ebp_df.head()), np.max(ebp_df.head())
    dictionary_of_metrics(gauteng) = round(my_list, 2)

    return dictionary_of_metrics(gauteng)
```

​

```
### END FUNCTION   File "<ipython-input-4-26c528bf55d1>", line 4
    dictionary_of_metrics(gauteng) = round(my_list, 2)`enter code here`
    ^ SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def dictionary_of_metrics(items):
my_dict = {
    "mean": round(np.mean(items),2),
    "median": round(np.median(items),2),
    "std": round(np.std(items, ddof= 1),2),
    "var": round(np.var(items, ddof= 1),2),        
    "min": round(np.min(items),2),
    "max": round(np.max(items),2),    
}

return my_dict
```